# can not connect to adhoc wifi connection even after rooting and change of file. Any Solutions?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, reverse-tether, ad-hoc-networks

I am posting here as I'm not allowed to post in Developers section as of being new here.

I want to enable adhoc wifi on my mobile. Followed the instructions here
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1669766

First,where's the download link? The 1st comment? If yes, I tried using those files. Now wifi gets disabled after every 30 second. Any turnarounds? 
Actually, When I use this file. It can not detect the MAC address of my device. Any ideas?

Or some other way to enable adhoc wifi on the device?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/17071/1465) might be helpful.

Comment: @MatthewRead thnx for the reply. But, have seen few using adhoc on same configuration device as mine. Have tried connectify too. Issues is with config file itself