# Android Ad-Hoc Wi-Fi support

Tags: wi-fi, ad-hoc-networks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does any version of Android support ad-hoc connections?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections)

Which versions of Android do support Ad-Hoc (peer-to-peer) Wi-Fi? Or neither? Where to read about it? May be some table somewhere?

P.S. I mean without rooting.

Comment: None so far AFAIK. Long on the wishlist, though.

Comment: Android does not support ad hoc mode, but Wi-Fi Direct is a a superior form of peer to peer network (non infrastructure). Wifi Direct does not require any hardware changes, and provides better service discovery, security, and speed than what is possible thorough ad hoc. Wifi Direct is supported since Android 4.0.

Comment: But does WiFi direct supported by other computers with WiFi cards?